# Attachment_Fu thumbnail width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thumbnails, attachment-fu

Any ideas on how to get the width and height of the thumbnail image? photo.width returns the original photos width. I am storing the width of the thumbnail in the database, I'm just not sure how to access that object.

Doesn't work:

```
<%= image_tag photo.authenticated_s3_url(:medium),
              :width => photo.width,
              :height => photo.height %>
```

Neither does this:

```
<%= image_tag photo.authenticated_s3_url(:medium),
              :width => photo.authenticated_s3_url(:medium).width,
              :height => photo.authenticated_s3_url(:medium).height %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, attachment_fu only loads the parent photo from a table to get info like the url. When you pass it a thumbnail option it simply appends the appropriate size to the end of the filename before the extension.

If you want to get the size, you're going to need to look it up in the table with something like, Photo.find_by_parent_id(photo.id, :conditions => ['thumbnail = ?', 'thumbnail_class_name']).width

You're better off knowing the width of a photo beforehand, at least if you're going to be using this for anything that would be run often.

Answer (score 0):

```
 :thumbnails => { :crop_200x200 => 'c200x200',
              :default_200x200 => '200x200',
              :ex_200x200 => '200x200!',
              :gt_200x200 => '200x200>',
              :lt_200x200 => '200x200<'}
```

To get the height and width this is what I would do

```
tname = 'crop_200x200'
height= @picture.thumbnails.select{ |r| r.thumbnail ==  tname }.first.height 
width= @picture.thumbnails.select{ |r| r.thumbnail == tname }.first.width
```